При сложении двух чисел, больше 100, код не работает
Особо не разбираюсь, но хотел написать сложение 2ух чисел, без их ввода по отдельности. Я додумался лишь для того, чтобы искать знак "+" и потом складывать числа, которые стоят перед этим знаком и после. 1+1 или 20+20 - работают, а вот например: 100+100 уже нет.
ex = input()
b = ex.find('+')
if str(b) in ex:
    print(int(ex[:b])+int(ex[b:]))


Опишите что делает код if str(b) in ex:.

find возвращает индекс символа и -1, если он не найден. Что вы проверяете через if str(b) in ex: - совершенно непонятно. Нужно проверять b > -1

Ну если условие подмахнуть на if b != -1: то работает ️‍♂️

Небезынтересная задача: когда этот код работает, когда нет и что бывает чаще?

Спасибо большое, только вот знаете почему же 100+100 не работает? Связи с чем при сложении больших чисел, программа не может найти даже индекс плюса, хотя с маленькими проблем нет?

Ну вы поверку то поменяли?

Можно, например, методом split разбить строку на список из числа до плюса и после, функцией map (или генератором) конвертировать числа-строки в числа-числа и суммировать.
print(sum(map(int, ex.split('+'))))

или
print(sum(int(x) for x in ex.split('+')))


Можно всё проще реализовать:
print(eval(input())

Функция eval() выполняет выражение на основе заданной строки

Eval is evil. Хотя в учебных целях можно.
